# Setting Move and Scale Box for iOS

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have seen several apps that after you take a picture, it shows a view for Move and Scale your picture, with a box showing what the resulting image will look like.  My app takes a picture the user takes or picks from library, and adds it to a PDF file.  I need this file to be a certain size to fit on the PDF, so I need to set the move and scale box accordingly, but I cannot find any documentation on how to do this.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Is fitting and cropping after selection an option?

Comment: Not wanting to stretch or distort anything on the image they choose, and since they can have access to portrait and landscape style pictures, figure it best to show them the size their image will be, so they can adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Just set the UIImagePickerController instance's `allowsEditing` to **YES**.

```
_imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
...
_imagePickerController.delegate = self;
_imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

The UIImagePickerController picker ONLY performs 320x320 cropping.

Try using this: https://github.com/gekitz/GKImagePicker (GKImagePicker)

Sample Code:

```
self.imagePicker = [[GKImagePicker alloc] init];
self.imagePicker.cropSize = CGSizeMake(320, 90);
self.imagePicker.delegate = self;

[self presentModalViewController:self.imagePicker.imagePickerController animated:YES];
```